# Sqlalchemy How can I slice string and covert it to int then check that is it greater than a number?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is my db.class:

```
def Table(db.Model):
    uid = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

The `uid` column like '201414111', '201633', '2012411'...

The first four characters means year.

The SQL is `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTR(uid, 0, 5)::INT > 2014"`

#### I want to get all datas which after 2014.

#### How can I write it by Sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

You can access the SQL SUBSTR function through the sqlalchemy.func module. You can then use this in a filter:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

res = session.query(Table).filter(int(func.substr(Table.uid,0,5)) > 2014).all()

for r in row in res:
    #do stuff...
```